# Phantom Reviews

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

For the past while, SE has insisted that there are several pending reviews in the queue up in the top bar, but as far as I can tell, the queue has been cleared:

[image]

Is this a glitch? Or is there something that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Would it be better to ask this question on meta.SE?

Comment: This question has been asked in various metas, and is fully answered. That number is the pending reviews, nor just the ones for you :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Thanks, good to know, but is it necessary to know that there are pending reviews if you can't see which reviews are pending? Or is there a way to see the list of pending reviews?

Comment: Yeah - that has been discussed at great length. I'm with you on this - I'd rather only see those that I can deal with, but it seems this is the way it is designed.

Comment: http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/572/delayed-flow-of-information-in-notifications

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find where I read it but there are two things that could be going on here:

1. The counter displays the *total number of tasks* that are available for review. This may also include such that you cannot do for some reason. Think of questions to close where you already have voted but there are still votes needed to get a close decision or reviews that you skipped for some reason.
2. To reduce server load the review notification is not refreshed continuously, so it might display values that are already outdated.